# How would I tell Python to read my text file?

Tags: python

```
def inputbook():
    question1 = input("Do you want to input book?yes/no:")
    if question1 == "yes":
        author = input("Please input author:")
        bookname = input("Please input book name:")
        isbn = input("Please input ISBN code")
        f = open("books.txt", "a")
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(author )
        f.write(bookname )
        f.write(isbn )
        f.close()
    elif question1 == "no":
        input("Press <enter>")
inputbook();
```

So I have code like this and I when I write last string (isbn), and I want python to read books.txt file. How am i supposed to do it?

Comment: You will want to add linebreaks (or other separation characters) after each `f.write(..)` otherwise you end up with a long line where you won’t be able to distinguish between the different values. You could also take a look at the [csv](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with your open, which renders it unreadable.
You need to open it with:

```
f = open("books.txt", "+r")
```

"a" stands for appending, so you won't be able to read books.txt with f.

Second, readlines or readline are not good options for your code as of now. You need to update your write method. Since inside the .txt file, the author, bookname and isbn will be messed together, and you are not able to separate them.

Answer (score 0):

```
def inputbook():

    question1 = raw_input("Do you want to input book? (yes/no):")

    if question1 == "yes":
        author = raw_input("Please input author:")
        bookname = raw_input("Please input book name:")
        isbn = raw_input("Please input ISBN code:")
        f = open("books.txt", "a+")
        f.write("%s | %s | %s\n" % (author, bookname, isbn))
        f.close()

    elif question1 == "no":
        raw_input("Press <enter>")
        try:
            print open('books.txt', 'r').read()
        except IOError:
            print 'no book'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputbook()
```